# change specific value of an obj with dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i want to sett the errors that im getting from express validator i did include the image of that array in the question for example if there is an error on the email i want to set it on the errorsInitState in email

[image]

this is the error initstate

```
export const errorsInitState = {
  errors: {
    email: {
      msg: ""
    },
    password: {
      msg: ""
    },
    confirmPassword: {
      msg: ""
    }
  }
};
```

i did try this but it didnt work for me

```
export const RegisterReducer = (state = errorsInitState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case FAILIED_REGISTRATION:
      return {
        ...state,
        errors: {
          ...state.errors,
          errors: payload.map(err =>
            err.param === "email"
              ? { ...err, msg: err.msg }
              : err.param === "password"
              ? { ...err, msg: err.msg }
              : err.param === "confirmPassword"
              ? { ...err, msg: err.msg }
              : ""
          )
        }
      };
  }
};
```

Comment: It's unclear what is not working and what is the expected behaviour.

Comment: `change value of register reducer to set the errors from express validator array` whh...can you rephrase this?

Comment: i want to sett the errors that im getting from express validator i did include the image of that array in the question for example if there is an error on the email i want to set it on the errorsInitState in email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good use case for this amount of ES6 spread construction craziness. Try this instead:

```js
const RegisterReducer = (state = errorsInitState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case FAILIED_REGISTRATION:
      return { 
        errors: {
          ...state.errors,
          ...payload.reduce((obj, { param, ...rest }) => {
            obj[param] = { ...rest };
            return obj;
          }, {})
        }
      };
  }
};

//code below is for demonstration
var errorsInitState = { errors: { email: { msg: "" }, password: { msg: "" }, confirmPassword: { msg: "" } } };
var FAILIED_REGISTRATION = 1;
var errors = [ { msg: "Email is required", param: "email" }, { msg: "Please entre a password with 6 or more characters", param: "password" } ];

console.log(RegisterReducer(errorsInitState, { type: FAILIED_REGISTRATION, payload: errors }));
```

Comment: Deep copy isn't needed, prone to create unnecessary re-renders as well, lossy (though shouldn't be a problem with state) and this technique is known to be the slowest anyway. A couple shallow clones is way better than this. In all the years I developed frontend applications, I never once needed a deep clone. Deep cloning is code smell, it's a sign that you've failed to isolate the data in manageable chunks.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I admit to not being familiar with `react` beyond that you are to some extent strictly disallowed to modify the `state`. Since the asker's function accepts state as a parameter, I'm assuming other properties may be on it too aside from those given in the template. In these conditions, I think it is necessary to have a deep copy, otherwise any lingering object references shared between both copies that get modified will also modify the `state`, which I understand to be unacceptable. The only other way I see is iteratively shallow copying the state. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: You shouldn't copy other properties of state if you're not going to change them since React will use shallow comparison to check if they changed. Say `state.otherThing` didn't changed, but since you've deep cloned the state, now the components using it will re-render as well.

Comment: The best way would be something like this: `errors: { ...state.errors, ...payload.reduce((errors, { param, msg }) => ({ ...errors, [param]: { msg }  }), {}) }`

Comment: @EmileBergeron I've edited the answer with your suggestion.